# Issue in javascript with variable/while loop condition

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I run the code and input "yes" when prompted, but the while loop won't run. What's the problem with my code?

```
var answer = prompt("Would you like to buy something?").toLowerCase

while (answer === "yes") {
 var type = prompt("What item would you like to buy?").toLowerCase;
}
```

By the way, this is just the area around the while loop. The rest of the code is at https://www.codecademy.com/alangdorf/codebits/uAlblD .

Comment: Um... where's your closing bracket (`}`)?

Comment: It's farther down in the code. I didn't include it in the snippet in the question.

Comment: are you sure you don't mean
if (answer === "yes")  {

}

Comment: Yeah. at the end of the loop, it asks the question again, and runs the loop again if the user answers yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you aren't actually executing the `toLowerCase` function. Right now, the `answer` variable is the `toLowerCase` function, you want it to be the *result* of the `toLowerCase` function:

```js
var answer = prompt("Would you like to buy something?").toLowerCase();

while (answer === 'yes') {
  var type = prompt("What item would you like to buy?").toLowerCase();
}
```

You can see it working by running the above snippet or running this working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/c3d4xekr/).

**UPDATE:** As noted by [chriskelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831775/chriskelly) in the comments, this will become an infinite loop because after entering the `while`, answer will always be 'yes' and your loop condition will never be false.

Answer (score 0):

Your `prompt(...).toLowerCase` will return a **function** here, not a string: The function `toLowerCase()`.

As `answer` contains a reference to a function comparing it with `"yes"` will always fail.

Use round brackets to call a function. I think calling the function is what you intend to do here.